# IComparable CompareTo(), How can I implement comparison on 2 different fields

Tags: c#, .net, icomparable

I Have a class like so :

```
public class Incident : IComparable<Incident>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IncidentType { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Incident other)
    {
        string str = other.Description;
        int ret = -1;
        if (String.Compare(Description, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            ret = 1;
        else if (String.Compare(Description, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            ret = -1;
        else if (String.Compare(Description, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            ret = 0;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I can sort objects of this class alphabetically based on the description field. 
How can I sort the class based on IncidentType field ?

I do not want to sort them on both fields simultaneously. 
Sometimes I want to sort incidents by `Description`, sometimes on `IncidentType`

Comment: What are you using for sorting? `List.Sort()`? `OrderBy()`? Something else?

Comment: Using OrderBy() to sort.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but a helpful tip. You can reduce the number of comparisons from 3 to 1 by doing `int ret = String.Compare(Description, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`, and then return `ret`. `CompareTo` doesn't say that the return value has to be `-1` or `0` or `1`. It says that it has to be `< 0`, `0`, or `> 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a typical case for you to sort either by `Description` or by `IncidentType`, you can implement different *Comparers* to sort on *different conditions*

```
public class Incident: IComparable<Incident> {
  ...

  private IncidentTypeComparerClass: IComparer<Incident> {
    public int Compare(Incident x, Incident y) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return 0;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        return -1;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, y))
        return 1;

      return String.Compare(x.IncidentType, y.IncidentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }    
  }

  // Additional comparer, by IncidentType 
  public static readonly ByIncidentTypeComparer: IComparer<Incident> = new IncidentTypeComparerClass();

  ...
}

...

List<Incident> incidents = ...

// Sort by IncidentType    
incidents.Sort(Incident.ByIncidentTypeComparer);
...
// Default sort (that's by Description)
incidents.Sort();
```

In case you want to sort by IncidentType only *once* or twice you can do it *explicitly*:

```
List<Incident> incidents = ...

incidents.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.IncidentType, 
                                        y.IncidentType, 
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `IComparer<T>` in seperate class and you can use this comparer when you sorting your elements:

```
public class IncidentComparer : IComparer<Incident>
{
    public int Compare(Incident x, Incident y)
    {
        return x.IncidentType.CompareTo(y.IncidentType);
    }
}
```

For example if you have a list like this, you can use your comparer:

```
List<Incident> incidents = new List<Incident>();
...
incidents.Sort(new IncidentComparer());
```

Or alternatively you can use `LINQ` instead:

```
incidents = incidents.OrderBy(x => x.IncidentType).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Another option is to supply a [Comparison delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx). As in `incidents.Sort((x,y) => x.IncidentType.CompareTo(y.IncidentType));`

Answer (score 2):

You can return a value earlier than the end of a function, so you can have an if statement         the checks if ret is 0 and returns ret if it's true. If it's not true, the if statement will be skipped and the rest of the function will be evaluated. For example:

```
public class Incident : IComparable<Incident>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IncidentType { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Incident other)
    {
        string str = other.Description;
        int ret = String.Compare(str, Description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (ret != 0)
            return ret;
        str = other.IncidentType;
        ret = String.Compare(str, IncidentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

will sort by Description, and if the Descriptions are the same, then it will sort by IncidentType. If you want sorting by IncidentType first, switch the two.

Comment: Don't use `-`, swap the arguments instead. `-int.MinValue` is still negative.

Comment: Edited to reflect the comment

Comment: You misread the question: "I do not want to sort them on both fields simultaneously. Sometimes I want to sort incidents by `Description`, sometimes on `IncidentType`"

Comment: In that case, you'll need to modify the function signature to take another argument that allows you to select which one you want to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int CompareTo(Incident other)
    {
        string str = other.IncidentType;
        int ret = -1;
        if (String.Compare(IncidentType, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            ret = 1;
        else if (String.Compare(IncidentType, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            ret = -1;
        else if (String.Compare(IncidentType, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            ret = 0;

        return ret;
    }
```

Remember, this is just a plain string comparison on IncidentType. You might have to introduce more complex business rules here.

Answer (score 0):

To sort, if you have for example:

```
List<Indicent> listIncident = new List<Incident>(); 

//This to sort based on the incidentType
listIndicent = listIncident.OrderBy(x => x.IncidentType).ToList();

//This to sort based on the description
listIndicent = listIncident.OrderBy(x => x.Description).ToList();

//This to sort based on two
listIndicent = listIncident.OrderBy(x => x.Description).ThenBy(x => x.IncidentType).ToList();
```